# Матрица достижимости

Tags: алгоритм

По матрице смежности нужно построить матрицу достижимости. [Использую Алгоритм Флойда — Уоршелла:](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%A4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%A3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0)

```
for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                W[i][j] = (W[i][j] || (W[i][k] && W[k][j]));
```

На графе

```
0 1 0 0 0  
0 0 0 1 0  
0 1 0 0 0  
0 0 1 0 0  
1 0 1 1 0
```

Данный алгоритм выдает:

```
0 1 1 1 0  
0 1 1 1 0  
0 1 1 1 0  
0 1 1 1 0  
1 1 1 1 0
```

Но на сайте у них получилась немного другая матрица. [T(D)](http://atomlex.narod.ru/discret/examples.htm)
Где ошибка?

Comment: Не знаю, в чем ошибка, но на главной диагонали точно должны быть единицы, т.к. каждая вершина достижима сама из себя.

Comment: Я тоже так думал, но [здесь](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8) тоже получают матрицу, в которой есть нулевые диагональные элементы.

Comment: видимо это вопрос соглашений, считать ли пути нулевой длины валидными путями. В примере на atomlex считают пути нулевой длины валидными, там берут дизъюнкцию A^0 V A^1 V ... V A^ (N - 1), где (A^ 0 = E). На википедии же A^1 V ... V A^N. Вроде так.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Никакой ошибки нет.

Посмотрите внимательно на граф:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Из узлов 2 3 4 можно добраться "из себя в себя" по некоторому пути.
А из узлов 1 и 5 "в себя" не доберёшься.
Поэтому такая матрица и получается:

```
0 1 1 1 0  
0 1 1 1 0  
0 1 1 1 0  
0 1 1 1 0  
1 1 1 1 0
```

Если вам для задачи этой информации не требуется, то после работы алгоритма можно пробежаться по диагональным элементам и проставить единички.